# shortest path algorithm with expected cost

Tags: python, probability, shortest-path, dijkstra, cost-based-optimizer

My objective is to calculate the expected cost for each path from the starting point to the end point and identify the minimum expected cost for each path when the respective node serves as the starting point.

So fistly : I have to find all possible paths

secondly : calculate expected cost for each path

Action_type_1 can be the end point, while Action_type_2 cannot serve as the end point.

Action_type 1 includes actions A and B, whereas Action_type 2 comprises actions C and D.

Each node is assigned a cost, assumed to be 1 for all nodes.

We can conceptualize the paths to the end point as follows:

If A is the starting point:

A -> B

A -> C -> B

If B is the starting point:

B -> A

B -> D -> A

The same applies to C and D, such as

C -> A -> D -> B.

Here is an example:

[image]

When comparing the expected costs of two paths, I can select the path from A to B with the lower expected cost."

I have a python code to calculate expected cost for each path :

```
def expected_cost(graph, node, end_nodes):
   if node in end_nodes:
        return graph[node]['cost']
   total_cost = 0
   for neighbor, probability in graph[node]['neighbors'].items():
        total_cost += probability * (graph[node]['cost'] + expected_cost(graph, neighbor, end_nodes))
   return total_cost

graph1 = {
    'A': {'cost': 1, 'neighbors': {'end': 0.5, 'B': 0.5}},
    'end': {'cost': 0, 'neighbors': {}},
    'B': {'cost': 1, 'neighbors': {'end': 1}},  # End Node
}

graph2 = {
    'A': {'cost': 1, 'neighbors': {'end': 0.5, 'C': 0.5}},
    'end': {'cost': 0, 'neighbors': {}},
    'B_yes': {'cost': 1, 'neighbors': {'end': 1}},  # End Node
    'B_no': {'cost': 1, 'neighbors': {'end': 1}},  # End Node
    'C': {'cost': 1, 'neighbors': {'B_yes': 0.8, 'B_no': 0.2}},
}

end_nodes = ['end']
expected_cost_A_1 = expected_cost(graph1, 'A', end_nodes)
print("Expected cost at node A of graph1:", expected_cost_A_1)
expected_cost_A_2 = expected_cost(graph2, 'A', end_nodes)
print("Expected cost at node A of graph2:", expected_cost_A_2)
```

Expected cost at node A of graph1: 1.5

Expected cost at node A of graph2: 2.0

But, it is not clear :

1. To find all possible path. I think it is related with permutation. But its big O is O(nCr)...maybe we need some heuristic approch ?
2. Calculate expected cost for each path. I think we can use some existing shortest path find algorithm like dijkstra algorithm.

Can you help me ?

Comment: Your notation is confusing. Your image shows a *directed* graph. But then you have `B -> D -> A` for example and I have no idea what this represents in light of that graph. Even if the graph were not directed, there is no direct path from B to D. So what are you expressing with that notation?

Comment: @Booboo Thanks for your comments.  Image above is just an example for path starting with A node. That is the reason why you cannot see the path starting with other node like B.

Comment: Then your graph is not directed and your diagram is misleading (you could replace arrows with simple lines).

Comment: A common version of Dijkstra's Algorithm computes a minimal path from some node X to *every* node in the graph. So if your graph is not directed, then you could use Dijkstra to compute the minimal paths starting from what you would consider the "ending" point. For example, if you want the path lengths for every node to B, then use Dijkstra to find the path lengths from B to every node.